# TextView and cursor position

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView and number buttons to type inside the TextView like a calculator.
I need to keep the cursor to stay in its place when I am typing the numbers and NOT to move.

For example lets say this is the cursor "[" , so this is what's happening now:

[12345

**What I want when I am typing the numbers**

12345[

This numbers are just an example, what is important for me is the cursor stay at the right and not to move.

**Update:**
[12345 the first number what I typed is 5 and the last one is 1.

Comment: TextView yourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_name); yourText.setText(yourText.getText() + newChar);

Comment: the gravity is right for textview. is there any way to set the gravity for cursor?

Comment: It depends on how you set the text in the text view, that is what I was implying with my comment :)

Comment: :) what I have is a calculator, I can't set any text for it.

Answer (score 1):

For EditText you can change the cursor for the view.  If you are currently manipulating the cursor position in your TextView, then you can do something similar in the code if need be.  There might be an automated way to do so, but I had thought setting the gravity as others had mentioned would do the trick.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.calculatorEditTextView);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Comment: I have TextView, I can't use setSelection with textview :)

Comment: Understood. If changing it to an EditView doesn't work for you for some reason, then you will have to figure out a different approach.  You just need to make EditText editable false if you don't want it manually edited.

Comment: I think there is a way to do it, cause when I use the android keyboard its writing the way I want. but I have my own buttons to use as numbers. so the problem is not textview or edittext. but I will change it to edittext to see what is happening. if its works then I will give your answer currect :) thanks a lot

Comment: When I am doing it with EditText editText = (EditText)... its asking me to change it to final, do you know why?

Comment: Probably because you are doing so inside a thread.  That is the typical request of a threading environment.